# How to preview qml documents referencing c++ types?

Tags: qt, qml, qt-creator

I frequently use types defined at runtime in c++ in QML documents.  It works well, but not with the design view in Qt Creator or with the external preview tools.

For example, in c++:

```
qmlRegisterType<CustomVideoSource>("MyModule", 1, 0, "CustomVideoSource");
```

And in QML:

```
CustomVideoSource { id: customSource }
VideoOutput { source: customSource; anchors.fill: ... }
```

The "qmlscene" external preview tool quits with the error 'module "MyModule" is not installed'.

The design view is usable as a preview in simple cases, unusable in complex cases, but in any case slow and I can't edit code and see the preview at the same time.

I'm aware of the "dummy context" concept but 1) don't see how it applies in this case and 2) have never had much luck getting it to actually work in other cases when it should.

Does anyone have a good workflow?  Maybe I shouldn't be doing things this way at all?

BTW, I'm aware of the Qt forums and I'll probably ask there, too.  If I can catch them when they're not down/broken.

Update/clarification:

I'm aware of the options for implementing an extension to QML in C++.  My question is not about the mechanics of doing so but about how best to deal with the situation above, e.g., I'd like to register a type at runtime but still have quick previews for UI work.

I'm considering doing a fake plugin purely for preview purposes and passing it via -I to qmlscene.  Also modifying qmlscene itself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the strategy I ended up with, which has worked well so far:

1. To address the "MyModule" issue, I created a qml module with a qml/javascript dummy implementation of MyModule in a "dummyModules" subdirectory.  I run the qmlscene preview tool with "-I dummyModules" to make them visible for prototyping.  The modules are, of course, not included in release distributions.
2. I also have several context properties set from C++.  To make these work I use the "dummydata" feature of qmlscene.
3. I modified (hacked) qmlscene to reload the scene on ctrl-r.

This 1) solves the "MyModule" problem without creating a c++ plugin (impractical in my case) and 2) gives me side-by-side editing and previews.

I suspect this may work well with the Creator "Design" module, too.  IIRC it uses an external program called "qmlpuppet" which is probably similar to qmlscene.  But I haven't tried it.

Comment: For the lazy among us, could you add some sample code for 1)? thanks

Comment: here is some [sample code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33980010/how-to-preview-qml-documents-referencing-c-types/73283237#73283237)

Answer (score 1):

`qmlRegisterType()` will make the module available only internally to the executable. So any QML files using that module will not be loadable by the qml preview tool.

You can try to make a standalone QML module, with a `qmldir` file and a C++ plugin which can be loaded during runtime. Just follow the [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-modules-cppplugins.html).

Comment: Thanks for your comment.  Is making a new QML module your suggestion for a better workflow?  I haven't done it because it seems to add a lot of unnecessary complexity.  Easy integration with C++ is one of QML's big selling points, but it seems to break design and preview tools.

Comment: @TylerDaniel - it doesn't break anything, there is no better workflow, if you want to use C++ types in QML without including and registering the types in the executable, you have to implement them as plugins, which QML can load and register during runtime. If the C++ types are NOT in your executable, they have to come from somewhere, it doesn't work by magic, QML has no psychic powers to know what your C++ types are and what they do.

Comment: qmlRegisterType<>() is simple and convenient.  I say that it breaks design and preview tools because they seem to be mutually exclusive.  I'm not looking for psychic powers;  I'm looking for a better workflow.  For example: "The qmlscene source is <here>.  It's easy to add in a dummy qmlRegisterType<>() call <like this>."  Or perhaps "I create a dummy QML module and pass it to the previewer <like this>."  Etc.

Comment: @TylerDaniel - at the risk of repeating myself - unless C++ types are registered in the executable, the ONLY OTHER WAY is to use a QML module implemented as a C++ plugin. The key is in the term "plugin" - something that plugs in. Implementing a QML plugin is trivial, but if that's too complex for you, maybe programming is not for you.

Comment: Thanks, ddriver, very enlightening.

Comment: @TylerDaniel - you asked a question, I gave you the answer. The Qt people went and made it expansible, so that what you ask is made possible - use C++ objects from QML that are not included in the executable. But hey, if you don't like how it works, you can always try some of your `<like this>`es and who knows, it might just work ;)

Answer (score 1):

Here is some sample code showing what [Tyler Daniel's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33980010/how-to-preview-qml-documents-referencing-c-types/34192725#34192725) might look like.

```
myApp
├── main.qml
└── dummyModules
    └── MyModule
        ├── qmldir
        └── NewQmlType.qml
```

main.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.15
import MyModule 1.0

Row {
    NewQmlType{} // This is a c++ type we need to mock when using qmlscene
}
```

qmldir

```cs
module MyModule
# A module requires at least one type registered in order to be considered valid
NewQmlType 1.0 NewQmlType.qml
```

NewQmlType.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.15

Rectangle {
    width: 40
    height: 40
    color: "red"
}
```

run the following in a terminal to test

```
qmlscene -I dummyModules main.qml
```